# netcat recieves file but no event generated in the directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netcat, inotify

I have this script send files at specific intervals

```
nc 10.10.10.132 1234 < /path/to/the/file;
```

I have this script running at recieving end

```
nc -lkv 1234 > /home/tejas/Desktop/bmcom/a.tar.lzma;
```

and it gives following output when run

```
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 1234)
Connection from [10.10.10.1] port 1234 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 36673)
Connection closed, listening again.
Connection from [10.10.10.1] port 1234 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 36674)
Connection closed, listening again.
Connection from [10.10.10.1] port 1234 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 36675)
Connection closed, listening again.
Connection from [10.10.10.1] port 1234 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 36676)
Connection closed, listening again.
Connection from [10.10.10.1] port 1234 [tcp/*] accepted (family 2, sport 36677)
Connection closed, listening again.
```

But when I check events by using inotifywait -m /directory path. No events are generated when files are accepted.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `nc -lkv 1234 > outfile` will make `nc` not exit and all the output will be sent to one file. So only a single file will be created.

Comment: @redneb yes I figured that out . No events are generated after ./ MODIFY a.1473858797.tar.lzma . Does this mean it is continously getting written ? or it isn't getting written.

Comment: Possibly, I don't know if `inotifywait` would report that. Can't you check the size and/or the modification date? Also, are you sure you want to send all the output to a single file?